# Shortcuts created by Setup project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project, shortcut

I was working with a legacy project and need help with some shortcuts created, the problem is that those shortcuts appear to be non-standard because when you right click on them and in the target location only shows the name of the program grayed out.

I have seen those shortcuts before and had no problems. The current problem is that when running on Windows XP you can  the icon and get the run as different user, but in windows 7 that functionality is limited apparently only to the shortcuts that point explicitly to an "exe" file.

The final users need that functionality due to some policies and the current work around is to them create the shortcut manually. I need a way to create a standard shortcut via the setup project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's more likely to be a permission problem, rather than some type of "non-standard" shortcuts. I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: I already though of that and manually modified the permissions to match the ones of the manually created shortcut(working) and the problem persists.